# PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory incorrectly matching similar paths

Tags: solr, lucene

I am trying to use paths the PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory tokenizer to create facets to allow users to filter departments in my application. The reason for this is that the departments can have children and this seemed like the best way to deal with a hierarchical structure.

Currently I am using the following scheme.xml

```
<fieldType name="text_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer>
        <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="|" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>

<field name="department_path" type="text_path" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

However this is causing problems with the matching, To give some examples when searching "department_path:Ovens & Hobs|Gas Hobs" the following should match:

- Ovens & Hobs|Gas Hobs
- Ovens & Hobs|Gas Hobs|Gas Hob(60cm)

The following should not:

- Ovens & Hobs
- Ovens & Hobs|Ovens
- Worktops
- Worktops|Hob Splashbacks

With the current setup I am getting results that contain similar names such as:

- Worktops & Splashbacks|Kitchen Splashbacks|Hob Splashbacks|Hob Splashbacks Steel|Hob Splashback
- Ovens & Hobs|Electric Hobs|Induction Hobs|Induction Hob 60cm

If somebody has any idea how I should change the type that would be great.

Thanks

Edit:

After changing my schema.xml to

```
<fieldType name="descendent_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="\" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

it is almost working however when searching for a leaf node eg 'Ovens & Hobs|Gas Hobs|Gas Hob(60cm)' I get results that should not match.

Comment: It's not completely clear to me what your documents look like, but the Solr analysis page would definitely help you understanding what's going wrong. One of the problems might be that you're appying the PathTokenizer at query time too.

Comment: Hi, I will have a look at the analyser but here are some examples of the documents. https://gist.github.com/4406292

Comment: Hi, So I played around with the analyser and I found that the | character was causing problems with the KeywordTokenizerFactory and causing it to split. I have changed the path to use / instead but the fact that this happened seems a bit strange. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Nice to know that you found the issue, maybe you can add your own answer for other people. That's how the keyword tokenizer works, but why do you need it? Anyway, you can perhaps configure its behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so for anybody reading this in the future there were two problems with my code. The first was that I was running the PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory during both indexing and querying. For my needs I just needed to run this tokenizer during indexing. The resulting type is:

```
<fieldType name="descendent_path" class="solr.TextField">
    <analyzer type="index">
        <tokenizer class="solr.PathHierarchyTokenizerFactory" delimiter="|" />
    </analyzer>
    <analyzer type="query">
        <tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory" />
    </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

The other issue was that I was not properly escaping the input which caused problems with some of the department names.